# libpq: which lib files should I use

Tags: c++, c, windows, postgresql, libpq

I used the PostgreSQL as my data base and I am coding a c++ project, so I have to use the [libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq.html) to connect it.

I have already found the include file and lib file in the PostgreSQL file but there are too many files. I think I don't need to add them all.
For the include file, I just added `libpq-fe.h`, `pg_config_ext.h` and `postgres_ext.h`, then I included the `libpq-fe.h`, it seems that everything goes well, I can call some functions such as `PQconnectdb`, `PQexec` etc. But when I compile it, I get some LNK errors, meaning that I didn't add the right lib files.
I've tried to add `libpq.lib` and `libpq.dll`, but I still got the LNK errors.
Does someone know which lib files should I add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error because of the wrong version.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809204/access-postgresql-via-c-interface-linker-error) is a same problem which has been solved.